# Any C# SmartDate converters out there, e.g. "sun 11" --> 2009-12-06 11:00:00

Tags: c#, date, user-experience

**In the spirit of not reinventing the wheel, can anyone point me to free C# code that does the following kinds of conversions?**

- "**sun**" --> 2009-12-06 00:00:00
- "**tom**" --> 2009-12-06 00:00:00
- "**tomorrow**" --> 2009-12-06 00:00:00
- "**mon 8pm**" --> 2009-12-07 20:00:00
- "**jan 5 at 10**" --> 2010-01-05 10:00:00

and **durations** that return two datetimes like this:

- "**jan 5, 8pm to 10**" --> 2010-01-05 20:00:00, 2010-01-05 22:00:00

the point is for developers to have a library which allows users to enter in **upcoming dates** in their own terms so that if you want to type in that you want to get a task done on "**Friday**" you just have to type "**fri**" and the **computer knows what you mean**.

Comment: I'd love to see something exist for .Net but I've only ever heard of datejs provide this functionality. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your users are actually people sitting behind a browser, than this library might be just what you are looking for:   [www.datejs.com](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: and if he's willing to convert code to C# it's also just what he's looking for. ;-)

Comment: jason: admittedly, it's not the best answer in the world. ;^)